# Multisite/Network What file to edit to change the "new blog" registration text

Tags: user-registration, signup, wp-signup

I'm not able to find the correct file to edit text.

What file do I edit in order to change the text in the picture below? I thought it was `wp-signup.php`, but the text is not there. Thanks for any help!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The message seem to be coming from `confirm_blog_signup()` which *is* defined in `wp-signup.php`. Note that the site seems to be running outdated WP version and it is slightly different now.

However it is bad practice to just edit core file. There doesn't seem to be designated and/or easy way to change output there, so you might need to make use of [`gettext`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) filter to cleanly change those strings.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you. Also, I use a plugin to remove email verification. The plugin is where I had to change the text. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There're several [Dropins](http://wpengineer.com/2500/wordpress-dropins/) for WordPress. The one you (probably) mean is one of the following:

```
blog-deleted.php    | Own message, when a blog gets deleted     | If a blog gets deleted    Multisite installation
blog-inactive.php   | Own message, if a blog is set inactive    | If a blog becomes inactive    Multisite installation
blog-suspended.php  | Own message, if a blog got suspended      | When a blog gets marked as archive or spam    Multisite installation
```